# Why Jquery reloads once loaded images

Tags: jquery

Well on this test page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/03/testing-2_04.html
you can see that images only load if you scroll, it is what I want and then I have used a callback function so when someone click on buttons like (Bicycle, Motorcycle etc...) the script doesn't stop working rather it use the callback function. But here is a issue, I will explain what it is:

If you load images and then you click on those buttons it reloads the images even though they are not part of user cache but still it do that. I know it is not loading images rather just making it look like it is loading but still this effect takes up time. Is there anyway to handle this, so to make it understand that don't load images that are already in user cache?

Comment: Always post relevant markup and code **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use the callback function, I think it will solve the issue

Comment: no if I remove the call back function then, the buttons (Bicycle etc) when they are clicked the images will not appear, they will stop appearing, that's why I am using a call back